# Simple custom control - Force closed

Tags: android, subclass, forceclose

I have created an android project using eclipse.the default system generated code looked as below

```
    package com.rmycustomclass.bengler;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class RMyCustomClassActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
    }
```

I wanted to try a simple custom control , so i changed the code as below. when i searched the web to create a simple custom control there are mentioned like "create class by subclassing a View". so tried as below by modifying the code.but it was not running and always force closed.

```
package com.rmycustomclass.bengler;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class RMyCustomClassActivity extends View {

    private Paint myPaint;

    public RMyCustomClassActivity(Context cxt, AttributeSet attribute){

        super(cxt,attribute);
        init();

    }

    public RMyCustomClassActivity(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }



    public void init(){

        myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setTextSize(12);
        myPaint.setColor(0xFF668800);
        myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawText("TEEEST", 100, 100, myPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        this.setMeasuredDimension(150,200);     
    }



}
```

Below is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:text="Enter text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>

        <TableLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Button"
                 android:layout_weight="1">
            </Button>
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="40dip" android:text="My button" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
            <test.control 
              android:id="@+id/control" 
              android:layout_height="match_parent"> </test.control>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your LogCat errors so we can see what is happening.

Comment: Your View class has the same name as your Activity class, you should use a more descriptive name for your View... This could easily cause a conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a project in eclipse it links your activity (RMyCustomClassActivity in your case) as the launcher in Android manifest...But since you have changed the activity to a View
android runtime cannot find the activity to launch...See your manifest file and you will find your class as the launcher activity

Comment: can you pls tell me what should i change

Comment: For your Custom View, create a different class and use this view inside your activity/layout to test it out

Answer (score 0):

add  android:layout_width="match_parent"

```
<test.control 
          android:id="@+id/control" 
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
>
```